# how to rewrite this simple url?

Tags: mod-rewrite

how can i rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/someURLhere
```

into

```
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=someURLhere
```

without mistaking local files, and directories as domains.

so i dont want

```
www.mysite.com/index.php 
www.mysite.com/admin/
```

to rewrite to

```
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=index.php
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=admin/
```

Comment: so `someURLhere` is a "virtual link" that doesnt really exist, yes?

Comment: it should be a url one can navigate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yoursite.com
DocumentRoot /www/yoursite

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ping.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

If this is a .htaccess file you dont need `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in both instances.

Comment: I could've swore I ran into an issue somewhere, where it was necessary to prepend the DOCUMENT_ROOT part..

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.