# how to send users directly to mod-rewrite url from a form?

Tags: php, search, mod-rewrite

i am using this form to search on my site

```
<form id="search" action="/search.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.value='';this.style.color='black'" value="Search here" name="tag" id="search-text" />
                    <input type="image" src="/search-new.gif" alt="Search" id="search-submit" />
              </form>
```

when i search with it i get a url like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/search.php?tag=query
```

but i am using rewrite rule in my site and i have url like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/query
```

This shows the same results

what i want is when user search 
instead of showing this url

```
http://www.mysite.com/search.php?tag=query
```

it should show my rewrite rule url

```
http://www.mysite.com/search/query
```

How i Cant Do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to rewrite this simple url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616963/how-to-rewrite-this-simple-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override the onSubmit() event of the form and redirect myself with javascript by changing window.location to the url you like (just concat the query value to the end)

here's a quick and super dirty example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function form_submitted()
    {
        var new_url = "http://www.mysite.com/search/" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('search-text').value);
        window.location = new_url;
        return false;
    }

</script>

<form id="search" onsubmit="return form_submitted()">
<input type="text" value="Search here" name="tag" id="search-text" />
<input type="image" src="/search-new.gif" alt="Search" id="search-submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'd keep the original `action` attribute and use JavaScript to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your form to GET /search/ and add a submit handler (in JavaScript) that creates the 'prettified' URL.

mod_rewrite rewrites the internal URL, not the URL that the user sees.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an external redirect with mod_rewrite to the prettified URL. See mod_rewrite documentation for "permanent redirects".

Since this requires an extra roundtrip (first a request is sent for `/search.php?tag=query`, an external permanent redirect to `/search/query` is sent, then the URL `/search/query` is fetched by the browser and only internally rewritten to the actual PHP script), I'd add a JavaScript shortcut as suggested in another reply (note that it will still work without JavaScript).